# preg_replace allow certain characters, delete short words

Tags: php, string

I have code that deletes any words that are 3 letters or less.

```
$result = trim( preg_replace
("/[^a-z0-9']+([a-z0-9']{1,3}[^a-z0-9']+)*/i","   ",$_POST['query']));
```

There are problems though. Firstly, I don't know how to allow certain characters (Polish to be exact, like ś, ć, ż etc).

Secondly, `preg_replace` deletes short words only when they are in the middle of the string, so if the string is something like "I like something" or even worse "I like it" the "I" and "it" will stay here. The only situation this works properly is when string is like "this is something" ("is" will be deleted from the string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be solution:

```
$re = '/\b\w{1,3}\b/u';
$str = 'Ściana jest biała a obraz jest kolorowy it is something';

$result = trim(preg_replace($re,"",$str));
echo $result;
//just in case, per comments, if some unwanted white spaces are left...

$res=preg_replace("%\s{2,}%"," ",$result);
echo $res;
```

I have added word boundaries, so all words less  than (or equal to) 3 chars should be replaced by spaces, AND, for Polish characters - you need `u` modifier. Please test and let me know if this works for you.

Online test: https://eval.in/706650

Comment: It works, but it outputs additional '' (empty string). This is a problem, because $result would be used to search my table and when there's LIKE '%%' in query then it will fetch literally EVERYTHING. It's still better than anything I tried so far, but I have to get rid of that empty string

Comment: @Vortic, no problem - replace with: ($re," ",$str)); one empty space, or, simple, with empty string, if that's goal? ($re,"",$str));?

Comment: This shows what's happening http://i.imgur.com/IBTrBeh.png basiicly, your code somehow creates empty string somewhere and that empty string is used later to search table (I underscored all empty strings in red). Normally I'd ignore that empty string but since it causes to fetch whole table it has to be fixed. I replaced code as you suggested but still the same results.

Comment: @Vortic, then try this: $res=preg_replace("%\s{2,}%"," ",$result); one replace more, before query - so, this must give words with ONE empty space between them, so you can split by that empty space. (You are splitting string latter, right?)

Comment: Now there's no empty string, but instead the code doesn't remove words that are 3 letters or less :)

Comment: And yes, string is exploded after using preg_replace

Comment: @Vortic, check edit, and new example link on eval.in - that's best i can do... :) P.S. If something's left, trim() exploded string parts, and process the query. :)

Comment: Np, glad to help. :)

Comment: just to let you know - if there's only one word in the string and it's short (1-3 letters) it won't be removed by your code but that can by easly solved by adding a pattern to the input that doesn't allow an input to have less than 4 characters.

Comment: Yet another solution. Instead of making a pattern (which turned out to be not the best) it's better to use str_replace("or nazwa like '%%' or opis like '%%' or tagi like '%%'","",$query) this removes any blank LIKE's that would appear in query if the first word in string is too short.

Comment: I meant my input pattern, not your preg_replace pattern of course. preg_replace pattern is still used.